# Excel individual cell formating

Tags: excel, formula

I would like to modify the cell format, so I can tipe in a positive or negative number, like -1, -11, or 11 and Excel would display it with some specific text around.
It should look like this:

-1 -> start-1KW

+11 -> start+11KW

etc.
I already acomplished to do so with positive numbers by using this phrase:

"start"##"KW"

It converts my number into the format: start5KW

But when I try to tipe in a negative value, it looks like this: -start5KW

The minus is in front of my first string. Would you have any idea, how I can modify my phrase to obtain the minus directly in front of my number? I do not want to use vba.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the custom format code:

```
"start"#"KW";"start"-#"KW"
```